# Can I Link XAMPP Server to Github?

Tags: php, github, xampp

How would I go about starting a XAMPP server that uses files from GitHub instead of htdocs?

The idea is that I have my PC on connected to my router and while I am away I can push or merge updates to GitHub, and they are automatically live as XAMPP would be pointed at my Repo.

Can this be done?
I know you can use gitpages, but php and server side code is critical to what we are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) in combination with your Xamp server in order to:

- listen to [push events](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#events) on GitHub, and,
- when said push is detected, `git pull` that repository in order to update your files